# Can an Android device send a fax traditionally?

Tags: fax

Can an android device send a fax *without internet access*, only via a phone/voice connection? (Since a message over the internet isn't really a fax now is it?)

Comment: [Send fax directly to or from phone without going through a web-based service?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/2078/send-fax-directly-to-or-from-phone-without-going-through-a-web-based-service)

Comment: @eldarerathis thanks, kind of disappointing that it is now 4 years later and still nothing